# How to mock Cookie.get('language') in JEST

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have a function which sets a language in cookie and gets it for some functionality. How do I set the value of language correctly for testing in JEST

```
function resolveLanguage () {
  // browser cookie is checked to see if there is a value for language
  const lang = Cookie.get('language')

  // If no lang, it is defaulted to en 
  return lang || 'en'
}
```

Now I want to test it in JEST

```
it('can resolve the language using a cookie', () => {
      Cookie.__defineGetter__("language", function() {
        return 'fr'
      })
      // console.log(Cookie.language) //returns fr
      // console.log(Cookie.get('language')) //returns fr
      expect(module.resolveLanguage()).toBe('fr') ---FAILS because it returns en
    })
```

Comment: Where does `Cookie` come from? do you import this as a module?

Comment: import Cookie from 'js-cookie'

Answer (score 59):

Don't have to download any deps, just use:

```js
Object.defineProperty(window.document, 'cookie', {
  writable: true,
  value: 'myCookie=omnomnom',
});
```

(`writable` needs to be set to true)

Comment: This was one of those answers that I've spent 4 hrs searching for. Thank you!

Comment: Here is an example: https://upokary.com/how-to-mock-cookie-inside-jest-in-reactjs/

Comment: Upvoted for the `omnomnom` part.

Answer (score 16):

You need to mock `js-cookie` using jest to set the language set you want.

```
import Cookie from 'js-cookie'

jest.mock('js-cookie', ()=> jest.fn())

Cookie.setMockImplementation(()=>({get: () => 'fr'}))
```

Or if you only need to set it once

```
jest.mock('js-cookie', ()=>({get: () => 'fr'}))
```

Note that this solution would always return 'fr' for all `Cookie.get` calls. If you need  support multiple values on get you could do something like this:

```
jest.mock('js-cookie', ()=>({get: key => {
   language: 'fr', 
   somethingElse: 'someThing'
}[key]}))
```

Comment: i want Cookie.get('language') to be 'fr', Where do I add this 'language'

Comment: tried jest.mock('js-cookie', ()=>({get: () => {
        language: 'fr'
      }})) . It still returns 'undefined' for Cookie.get('language')

Comment: So the `resolveLanguage` import `js-cookie`, could you please just `console.log(Cookie)` in this module. This should log the the jest mock.

Comment: Seems like mocking has no effect. You should post the full code of the `resolveLanguage ` module, otherwise its hard to get whats wrong.

Answer (score 12):

I tried this and it worked:

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

Cookies.get = jest.fn()
    .mockImplementation(() => 'fr');
```

If you want to return different values each time you call `Cookies.get()`, you can do this:

```
Cookies.get = jest.fn()
    .mockImplementationOnce(() => 'en') // first time
    .mockImplementationOnce(() => 'de'); // second time
```

Answer (score 8):

When using the [setFilesAfterEnv](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array) option in JEST, adding the following to the defined setup file works pretty well.

Enables normal cookie handling without any mocking.

```js
let __cookies;
Object.defineProperty( window.document, 'cookie', {
    get: () => __cookies,
    set: v => __cookies = v,
    split: s => __cookies.split( s ),
} );
```

Comment: Bruh. Finally. Thanks. If you're running React, you can add this to the bottom of the `src/setupTests.js` file. In your test, you can run something like `document.cookie="auth_token='hello'"`

Answer (score 3):

The below code helped with mocking set/get for cookies for all types of tests in Jest:

```
Object.defineProperty(document, "doctype", {
 value: "<!DOCTYPE html>"
});
let setCookie = (v) => v;

Object.defineProperty(window.navigator, 'cookieEnabled', (function (_value) {
  return {
    get: function _get() {
      return _value;
    },
    set: function _set(v) {
    _value = v;
    },
    configurable: true
  };
})(window.navigator.cookieEnabled));

setCookie = (v) => v;

Object.defineProperty(window.document, 'cookie', (function (_value) {
  return {
    get: function _get() {
      return _value;
    },
    set: function _set(v) {
      _value = setCookie(v);
    },
    configurable: true
  };
})(window.navigator.cookieEnabled));
```

Comment: This is a much better implementation.  It is best practice in unit test to avoid testing the underlying implementation.  In this case, if we focus on testing if a cookie is get or set, so even when the implementation would switch to different cookie library other than `js-cookie`, the unit test would still work.

Comment: Can you explain what the `setCookie` is and why it is assigned again in the middle of the code?

Answer (score 3):

It's not a good practice to either override `process` and `window` or mock libraries parsing `process` and `window`.

It's better to just spy on `process` and `window` props and mock them through the spy because:

- It keeps the original behavior intact.
- It makes strict-typing easier.
- This principle can be applied on any `window` or `process` prop.

With `clearMocks: true` in `jest.config.js`, this is a lot cleaner in my opinion:

```
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */

describe('Cookies', () => {
  const mockedWindowDocumentCookie = jest.spyOn(window.document, 'cookie', 'get')

  afterAll(() => {
    mockedWindowDocumentCookie.mockRestore()
  })

  test(`with fr-FR language`, async () => {
    mockedWindowDocumentCookie.mockReturnValueOnce('language=fr-FR')

    // ...
  })
})
```