# unit testing cookies with Jest

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have created a cookies helper in my codebase, and I am wanting to unit test, I have a function that looks like this,

```
static setDeviceCookie(cookieName: string, cookieValue: DeviceJson ) {
    console.log(cookieName);
    console.log(cookieValue);
    document.cookie = `${cookieName}=${JSON.stringify(cookieValue)}; max-age=31536000; path=/; domain=.meetupcall.com;`;
}
```

I am wanting to test with the jest that the cookie does indeed get created, I thought it would be as simple as in my test doing this,

```
describe('getCookieValue', () => {
    // Biggest thing was to create this document Object
    beforeEach(() => {
        DeviceCookies.setDeviceCookie('myDevices', dataStub);
    });    

    it('returns cookie value when found', () => {
        const result = DeviceCookies.getDeviceCookie('myDevices');
        console.log(result);
    });
```

});

Result is coming back a null? So I would a test cookies in Jest?

Comment: It's not null but undefined, because you don't return anything from a function. If the result is that document.cookie was assigned then assert it.

Comment: What's the implementation of the `getDeviceCookie` method?

Comment: This answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51978914/8486161